# All-aero window have controls' colors blended - how to avoid it

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, aero, dwm

I'm looking for a way to paint my custom controls into both the client and non-client area of a dialog. More or less the white area below

[image]

I used `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` and I managed to get that effect by extending the client area on the entire window with

```
MARGINS mar = {-1, -1, -1, -1};

DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea ( hWnd, &mar );
```

but now every control which I set with a transparent background

```
SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
```

have their colors blended with the aero stuff (the same problem [you can see here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15770/Vista-Goodies-in-C-Using-Glass-in-Your-UI#allglassdlg)).

Is there a way for the controls to retain their right color and avoid blending with the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the window treated the black colour as the transparency key.

You just need to set another value:

```
SetWindowLong(hWnd,GWL_EXSTYLE,WS_EX_LAYERED);
// Choose a colour that you will not use in the program, eg RGB(200,201,202)
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd,RGB(200,201,202),0,LWA_COLORKEY);
```